# ASP Html.BeginForm Multiple Submit Buttons - Adding Custom Confirmation without JQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, submit, confirmation

I am creating an asp web application that can't use JQuery and uses custom pop up dialogs.

I create a form using:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "recordsbook", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SubmitForm" })){%>
```

I have submit buttons:

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Next"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Previous"  name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="First"  name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Last"  name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Add Record"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Delete Record"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
```

I want to add a confirmation dialog for the Delete Record SubmitButton. For some reason when I add an onsubmit event to the input it gets skipped. If I change onsubmit to onclick the confirm dialog pops up but the background submit process happens in parallel and refreshes the page.

How can I add the onsubmit confirmation dialog to just the Delete Record submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe onclick needs to return false to stop the submission

Comment: The issue is that the onclick function does not run before the onsubmit code. The popup vanishes during a refresh of the page after the submission happens before one could click yes or no to return true or false.

Comment: Try making a post in .cs (server side file) instead of front end (asp) file. Maybe that'll fix it, I'm not sure.

Comment: Would something like this work? I've seen it in my google searches, but I'm not sure if it will actually submit the form.
`
        <asp:Button OnClientClick="return CustomConfirm();" 
                Text="Delete Record" runat="server"/>
`

Comment: Can't get it to work, I get an error saying type button must be in form tags. It's in within the form, right were the other delete button was.

Comment: <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "recordsbook", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SubmitForm", onsubmit="return (deleteConfirm())"}))
    { %>
This works the same way as my first issue. Now delete Confirm will run on all buttons but it gets beat out by cs process.

Comment: Why don't you have a seperate server side file? .cs file. It's just easier

Comment: I do, but I can't throw a confirm box from there.

Comment: Right but you should handle the post there. Not on the asp file.

Comment: The issue lies in the custom javascript, because I can't use jquery the confirm window is not modal. if you do a confirm in the submit code on click it works. I'll have to fix my javascript.